# what happend if I do not commit/rollback but do release in typeorm

Tags: sql, transactions, typeorm

suppose I have a statement:

```
await queryRunner.startTransaction();
if (blah blah) {
    await queryRunner.release();
}
```

`await queryRunner.commitTransaction` or `await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction` necessary? Or my statement can?